# Add first time value from multiple data sets to new column based on multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have two tables for recording testing, one has test info including a DataTime value and the other table has the info on the test. We'll call these tables Main and Info. Main has multiple rows for each test whereas Info only has one per test.

I want to add the starting time of each test to the Info table. There are multiple tests so I would need to find the first row of each test and then find the row in the Info table which is connected by a Job_Number.

e.g.

MainTable

| Time | JobNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-30 10:57:51 | 1500 |
| 2023-05-30 10:57:52 | 1500 |
| 2023-05-30 10:57:53 | 1500 |
| 2018-12-21 10:32:56 | 499 |
| 2018-12-21 10:32:57 | 499 |
| 2019-10-03 15:28:56 | 777 |

Then find the first row of each dataset and put it into the Info Table under the same JobNumber

Info Table

| Time | JobNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-30 10:57:51 | 1500 |
| 2018-12-21 10:32:56 | 499 |
| 2019-10-03 15:28:56 | 777 |

The reasoning behind this is that "JobNumber" is stored by manually inputting the value so there could be an integrity issue with the wrong value being uploaded. This Time value would make it easier to correct.

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine?

Comment: The SQL Database is hosted using Microsoft Azure. I'll add the tag now.

Comment: Don't do it, don't duplicate data in multiple tables, query it when you need it

Comment: I've updated the question with my reasoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Take the minimum time value for each JobNumber from Main table and then join the resulting data with Info table based on the matching JobNumber. Below is the code,

```sql
UPDATE Info
SET Time = Main.MinTime
FROM Info
JOIN (
    SELECT JobNumber, MIN(Time) AS MinTime
    FROM Main
    GROUP BY JobNumber
) AS Main ON Info.JobNumber = Main.JobNumber;
```

[DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rUMgcS-_)